# Ruby on Rails database workflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a bit of a Rails beginner, so I'm sorry if this question is easy. I'm wondering how I am supposed to modify the Rails database as a developer without letting users of the site modify data.

More information:
Let's say I am trying to create a website that lists books along with their information. I want users to be able to see these books, but not add/delete them. As a developer, I want a way to add books without using the command line (hard to edit mistakes). What's the easiest way for me to do this? Would there be any differences between the development database and a live hosted one?

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a few approaches to do this.

1. different user roles. This technically breaks the rule of `without letting users of the site modify data`, but being able to differentiate between `normal` and `admin` users means you can limit who actually can add data into the database. I used [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) as a way to authorize requests but I know there are others.
2. I agree doing it using the command line isn't ideal, but rails do support rake tasks. You can create a task that will handle most of the logic and all you need to do is something like

```
rake create_book["name here"]
```

This will make the process less error-prone.

3. Create data using rails migrations. Rails can generate the skeleton file for you, and you just ran any ActiveRecord methods. However, the main purpose of migration is to update the database schema, but they can seed the database as well. here's the example from the [dcos](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data)

> Would there be any differences between the development database and a live-hosted one?

Yea, they should be totally separate database instances. You don't want to have your development database be the same as the live one. This would cause major problems. Rails have a concept of environments where you can use different configurations, so you can pick and choose what database URL to use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I mean by differences in dev and live databases is, I'm wondering if there's any difference between how I would add to a dev database and a live one. It seem like with the solutions you've given me, the answer is no, I would just ssh into wherever the live is hosted and run things as if it was local?

Answer (score 1):

like [@davidhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6496010/davidhu) said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73676749/8773659) The best approach really is the use of authorization. If only admin can see a page to CRUD the books then you don't have to worry about normal users doing same plus it makes it easy for you as the admin to make changes or add to the collection. Add the gem (or reinvent the wheel) then Rails will take care of the rest for you.